# Rails server hangs when started with foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, foreman

Here's what my Procfile looks like:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

I intend to add a worker process because I wish to run some background jobs. I'm following [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) instructions

This is what I noticed:

- No problems encountered if the worker is started separately.
- When I keep the second line in the Procfile and don't not change anything else, the rails server serves a couple of requests and hangs after that
- As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Missing-Output) , I've added `STDOUT.sync = true` to config/environments/development.rb and verified the same in the rails console. Did not work.
- Tailed log/development.log and compared it against the stuff that foreman outputted to the shell and noticed that both matched for a couple of requests and then foreman stopped printing out stuff to the shell - the next request would then hang
- I updated foreman using foreman.pkg as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and verified the same with [6]
- It was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360806/724516) that this might be caused due to a stray debug statement. I'm not using the debugger and I do not have the pry gem or the ruby-debug gem in my Gemfile.lock
- I believe the symptoms are similar to this related unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359940/rails-foreman-worker-hangs-server)

Please help!

[6]:

```
which foreman
/usr/bin/foreman
ls -lah /usr/bin/foreman  # checked the updated date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked and resolved here:

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/244

TL;DR: Install the gem, don't use foreman.pkg

Answer (score 0):

I'll add than if you're using Heroku, the foreman version included with the heroku toolbelt has the same issue.

Use the one you can get with `gem install foreman` instead.